# Using floorf vs floor

Tags: ios, objective-c, floor, cgfloat, floor-division

I have the following situation in my code:

```
//maxiumumHeight and rowHeight are CGFloats
CGFloat rows = floorf(maximumHeight / rowHeight);
CGFloat height = (rows * rowHeight);
```

It works just fine, but I notice that when I use `floor`, it works fine also. I'm also confused about how to define `rows`, should it be an `NSUInteger` or `CGFloat`?

It seems to work fine in all scenarios, but I have a little trouble understanding floating point math and was wondering what is the optimal way to do this code? Or does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

`floor` is for `double` (which is same as `CGFloat`) and `floorf` is for `float` (meaning it takes `float` arguments). This comes from ol' C stuff. Since you use `CGFloat` stick with `floor`. But, just in case, I would add a bit of tolerance, so change it to e.g.

```
CGFloat rows = floor ( ( maximumHeight + 0.5 ) / rowHeight );
```

assuming these values are always strictly positive.

Often you'd convert the number of rows to integer but since you calculate a UI height with it, which is also going to be used as `CGFloat` no need to use integers here. (Note if you are on watch `CGFloat` is `float` so there you'd want to use `floorf` but FWIW on many architectures `floor` and `floorf` are one and the same).

Not sure if this is what is troubling you, but floor rounds down to nearest int. So if you have e.g. 100 pixels available and you want a row to have 20 pixels, you will have

```
100 / 20 = 5
```

rows. What if you want it to be 21 pixels? Then

```
100 / 21 = 4.76
```

Now you need to decide. If you are going to insert 4 rows here you use `floor` since

```
floor ( 4.7 ) = 4.0
```

and note that, since you use only 4 rows, the height of each row will be

```
100 / 4 = 25
```

pixels, a bit more (since you use *less* rows) than the 21 you hoped for.

If you in stead want to use 5 rows then use `ceil` or ceiling since

```
ceil ( 4.7 ) = 5.0
```

and here note that since you use *more* rows the height will be

```
100 / 5 = 20
```

pixels. So if the 21 you hoped for is a *maximum* you'd use `ceil` in this particular example. If it is a *minimum* likewise you'd use `floor`.

Sometimes you may get funny and unexpected values, something like

```
100 / 20 = 4.999999999
```

which is why I'd add a bit of tolerance.